# Kotlin. Array of Arrays works not properly

Tags: arrays, kotlin

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val (n, m) = readLine()!!.trim().split(' ')
    val nInt = n.toInt()
    val mInt = m.toInt()
    val blankArr = IntArray(mInt, { _ -> 0 } )
    var arr = Array(nInt, { _ -> blankArr })
    for (a in arr) {
        for (b in a)
            print(b.toString() + ' ')
        println()
    }
    arr[0][0] = 100
    for (a in arr) {
        for (b in a)
            print(b.toString() + ' ')
        println()
    }
}
```

CONSOLE:

```
4 4
0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 
100 0 0 0 
100 0 0 0 
100 0 0 0 
100 0 0 0
```

What am I doing wrong?

Should have been 100 in [0,0]. Instead of this there is a whole column filled with 100

Comment: Instead of padding your post you might want to explain what your code should do and what doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing

```
val blankArr = IntArray(mInt, { _ -> 0 } )
var arr = Array(nInt, { _ -> blankArr })
```

with

```
val blankArr = { IntArray(mInt) { _ -> 0 } }
var arr = Array(nInt, { _ -> blankArr() })
```

or

```
val blankArr = IntArray(mInt) { _ -> 0 }
var arr = Array(nInt, { _ -> blankArr.copyOf() })
```

Execution result will become

```
4 4
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
100 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
```

You asked:

> What am I doing wrong?

Your 2-dimension array is actually "an array whose elements are all pointing to the same array".
So make a copy of the original array will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you put the same `Array` reference into the surrounding array multiple times with this code:

```
val blankArr = IntArray(mInt, { _ -> 0 } )
var arr = Array(nInt, { _ -> blankArr })
```

You need to create copies of `blankArr` or change the initilization a bit:

```
fun print2DArray(arr: Array<Array<Int>>) {
    arr.forEach {a->
        println(a.joinToString(" ") { it.toString() })
    }
}
//...
val arr = Array(nInt, { _ -> Array(mInt) { 0 } })
arr[0][0] = 100
print2DArray(arr)
```

I made all of the array initialization in a single statement that creates independent nested arrays:

```
val arr = Array(nInt, { _ -> Array(mInt) { 0 } })
```